# How do we call a pair of sets $A,B$ such that there is some injection $f: A \to B$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, soft-question, terminology

Let $A,B$ be sets and let $f: A \to B$. If $f$ is a surjection, then we may simply write $f(A) = B$ or say in a more laborious way that $f$ maps $A$ onto $B$, to mean the same thing.

However, if $f$ is an injection, how do we abbreviate the thing that $f$ maps $A$ to $B$ in a one-one manner? I guess saying that $A$ is in injection with $B$ is misleading and hence not good, because it does not specify the "direction".

Comment: $A = f^{-1}(B)$ and $f(f^{-1}(B)) = B$.

Comment: I don't think the math-history tag is appropriate - the question isn't about the *evolution* of symbols, but the symbols themselves. I'm not so sure about the soft-question either.

Comment: Okay; thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3):

We say "$A$ injects into $B$", and may write $f: A \hookrightarrow B$.

Comment: In a similar way, you can also show a surjection with $f: A  \twoheadrightarrow B$